# How to ensure that sex with a new partner will be safe for health?

Tags: sex, physical-health

I want to be as certain as possible that sex with a new partner will not do any harm to my health. I know the common notion about "safe sex", but it seems oversimplified and generally primitive tools for the "most cases" protection, which isn't enough.

How do i ensure that sex with new partner will be safe? is there some kind of quick medical checkup or something?

EU/Poland

Comment: What diseases are you concerned about that don't fall under the heading of "most cases?"

Comment: I'm not sure this is really on topic for the site, as it is more of a discussion that you need to have with your potential partner

Comment: I'm just waiting for the OP to sign on again and see our comments and respond.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some kind of quick medical checkup or something?

It depends on what you mean by "quick" and how you wish to proceed.

If you wish to have the most speediest possible test, you can go private and pay for you and your partner to have a complete set of STD tests.

If you are not in such a hurry, although it is still quite quick, you can get tested here in the UK for free under the National Health Service by going to a sexual health clinic.

I am not sure about Poland but, in some countries, I believe you have to be referred by your primary care doctor.  If you are unsure of the route to go you can speak to your primary care doctor who will be happy to put you in the correct direction.